# Why does Github action log show asterisk?

Tags: github-actions

When running on a Github action runner the Maven log output shows only 3 asterisk (`***`) instead of the actual string

> Warning:
> /home/runner/work/project/src/test/java/de/***/persistence/dao/DaoTest.java:98:
> Prefer java.time.ZonedDateTime

Where do these `***` come from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out that Github actions have a security feature that replaces strings that are also used as a secret.
So if some log output just by accident contains the same string as used as a secret elsewhere it does get replaced with `***`.

This is also mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/507).

Comment: What would we do when the intended string is necessary on a command, and don't want GitHub to substitute the string. In my case I have a secret for my username, but then I hard code my username when trying to build a Docker image which requires me to specify my username.

Comment: This is funny, I have a json secret, and it replaces curly brace in the output ¯\_(ツ)_/¯